# Monaca cloud: Display ios app name on the home screen in English or in Japanese

Tags: ios, iphone, plist, globalization, monaca

I am creating an app in MONACA cloud.
By using the language of the terminal , I want to switch the name of the icon on the home screen of ios in English or Japanese .

ex)
use English: Notepad/
use Japanese: Memo

I think that what should be editing the " MonacaApp-Info.plist " . But I do not know how do I edit . Please give me advice.

Answer (score 0):

On the left side in the navigation pane near the top you will find iOS. Expanding iOS, you will find the plist file.  Double-click to open and edit like any other file.  To create localized display names, reference this document:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-110725